# WinForms C# - Proper method to free draw?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm attempting to re-create something similar to Microsoft's Paint application. I'm using the Bitmap technique to render my drawings in order to have them be persistent. At 4 pixels x 4 pixels, it's unnoticeable, but as you go higher in the width, it's extremely noticeable, especially when you curve. I have a picture to show you what it looks like and some snippet.

[image: picture]

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Initializing Graphics and Bitmap
        pnlMain.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(pnlMain.Width, pnlMain.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        Doodle = Graphics.FromImage(pnlMain.BackgroundImage);
        Doodle.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Doodle.Clear(Color.White);
     }

private void pnlMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        start = e.Location;
        if (cboDrawType.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
        Painting = true;
        }

        private void pnlMain_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Painting = false;
    }

        private void pnlMain_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      if (Painting == true && cboDrawType.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            end = e.Location;
            Doodle.DrawLine(ChosenPen, start, end);
            pnlMain.Refresh();
        }
      start = end;
    }

        private void nudSize_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChosenPen.Width = Convert.ToUInt16(nudSize.Value);
    }
```

NOTE: start and end are new Point() variable members.
Sorry if the code is a bit messy, I had to cut it out brutally.
I'm using a pen even though it says Brush in the picture.
Doodle is my declared graphics

Comment: Bit hard to follow the code and what you've done to generate that image, but one thing I see is that you only set `start` in `MouseDown`, even though `end` is set on `MouseMove`.  Just a guess, but in `MouseMove` try adding `start = end;` at the end of the method.

Comment: I actually have that added, I should update my snippet. I used my cursor to draw the image when I hold down my mouse button.

Comment: Yes, I just realised that you *must* have that added or you'd end up with a whole lot of straight lines emanating from the start, and it would affect slow same as fast.

Comment: I think you need to show `Doodle.DrawLine`.  There is nothing here that is affected by pen size.

Comment: I'll add what I'm using to affect my pen size if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I thought Doodle was a custom class.  Naming conventions dude!  Well I don't know then, what have you tried in terms of debugging?  I'd be spitting out all start/end coordinates to debug console: `Debug.print("Move event, start x=" + start.x ... ", end y=" + end.y);`

Comment: I've noticed that the width of the pen strictly increases just the width. Is there no way to increase the entire pen's dimensions? Brushes with `.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.X, e.Y, Width, Length)` has this problem where if you go too fast, it leaves gaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should specify the `StartCap` and `EndCap` properties:

```
pen.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
pen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
```

The default is `Flat`, which turns short lines with a high pen width into silly stripes.

Comment: Perfect answer, I actually did not know this existed. Thanks.